# Switch statement in JavaScript function is not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a switch statement in a function, but it is not activating.

```js
let thisFunction = function(index) {

  console.log(index);

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      console.log('Home');
      break;

    case 1:
      console.log('About');
      break;

    case 2:
      console.log('Services');
      break;

    case 3:
      console.log('Portfolio');
      break;

    case 4:
      console.log('Contact');
      break;

    default:
      console.log('Default');
  }
};

$('nav ul li a').click(function() {
  let index = $(this).attr('data-btnIndex');
  thisFunction(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="0">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="1">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="2">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="3">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="4">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When I run the code above and click a link, the console.log of "index" runs but the switch block does nothing.

If I define the index variable like in the example below, the switch works.  But when I put the same code in the function, the switch stops working.

Example:

```
let index = 3;

console.log(index);
switch(index){
    case 0:
        console.log('Home');
    break;

    case 1:
        console.log('About');
    break;

    case 2:
        console.log('Services');
    break;

    case 3:
        console.log('Portfolio');
    break;

    case 4:
        console.log('Contact');
    break;

    default:
        console.log('Default');
}
```

This example returns "3" and "Portfolio" in the console, as it should.

Comment: Well, the obvious explanation here is that your call to `$(this).attr` is not returning a value covered by your `switch` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr` returns a *string*. (Your manual snippet is defining `index` as a *number*, which is why its behavior is different) Either test `case`s against numeric strings like `'0'`, or cast the `index` to a number first:

```js
let thisFunction = function(index) {

  console.log(index);

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      console.log('Home');
      break;

    case 1:
      console.log('About');
      break;

    case 2:
      console.log('Services');
      break;

    case 3:
      console.log('Portfolio');
      break;

    case 4:
      console.log('Contact');
      break;

    default:
      console.log('Default');
  }
};

$('nav ul li a').click(function() {
  let index = $(this).attr('data-btnIndex');
  console.log(typeof index);
  thisFunction(Number(index));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="0">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="1">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="2">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="3">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-btnIndex="4">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wouldn't JavaScript do an implicit cast in this case?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for your help!  I was dumbfounded.

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` vs `<a>`. I recommend you stick with anchor for navigation bcs that's what it's made for. Re the `dataset` attributes you are using, they are not required. Simply use the `innerHTML.toLowerCase()` for your switch.

Regarding your issue, your page is navigating away before your script gets to handle the `.click`.

Simply add a CSS class to whatever you want in the page HTML anchor. In other words, in `about.html` have `<a class="active-page">About</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine, but there is only one minor issue, that prevents the correct output. Your switch is not stopping, its running perfectly, but the type of the value of the attribute `data-btnIndex` is string. So instead of `case 0`, you should write `case '0'`, instead of `case 1` you should write `case '1'` and so on.

Or you you can parse the value of `data-btnIndex` to Integer by the following method:

```
var index = parseInt(index);
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks.